# How can I make a modal box appear over the entire Page

Tags: javascript, css

How I can make modal appear over the all page ?

```
 .modal {


   display: none; /* Hidden by default */
             position:relative;; /* Stay in place */
             z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
             padding-top: 50px; /* Location of the box */
             left: 0;
             top: 0;
             width: 100%; /* Full width */
             height: 100%; /* Full height */
             overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
             background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
             background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
         }

         /* Modal Content */
         .modal-content {
             position: relative;
             background-color: #fefefe;
             margin: auto;
             padding: 0;
             border: none solid #888;
             width:20%;
             height: auto;
             box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgbs(0,0,0,0.19);
             -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
             -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
             animation-name: animatetop;
             animation-duration: 1s
         }

         /* Add Animation */
         @-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
             from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
             to {top:0; opacity:1}
         }

         @keyframes animatetop {
             from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
             to {top:0; opacity:1}
         }

         /* The Close Button */
         .close {
             color: white;
             float: right;
             font-size: 28px;
             font-weight: bold;
         }

         .close:hover,
         .close:focus {
             color: #000;
             text-decoration: none;
             cursor: pointer;
         }

         .modal-header {
             background-color: #5cb85c;
             color: white;
         }

         .modal-body
          {
          width: 300px;
              }

         .modal-footer {
             padding: 2px 16px;
             background-color: #5cb85c;
             color: white;


         // Get the modal
         var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
         //Adiciona um eventListener a todos os elementos com a classe video, quando clicaldo chama a função é passada ao handler para ser executada
         //A funcção troca o estilo do display da modal box.
          const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.video');
          for( const btn of btns ) {
           btn.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
          }
          function handler(element)
          {
           modal.style.display = "block";
           //var source = $(element).find('video').attr('src');
           //window.alert(source);

          }

         //Seleciona todos os elementos com a classe video e quando o seu click for disparado cria uma função anonima que irá executar  todas as operaçãoes cada vez que um desses elementos for clicado.
          var vids = $('.video');
          vids.on('click', function() {
            var source = $(this).find('video').attr('src');;
            $('#video1').attr('src',source); // or whatever.
            //console.log(thing.prop('src'));
         })
         //Preferivel
         //var source = $('.video').on('click', function(event) { $(this/* which is also the original element in question  */).find('video').prop('src')});
         //$('#video1').attr('src',source);
         //$(element).on('click', function(event) { $(this/* which is also the original element in question  */).find('video').prop('src'); // so this should get the src property of any <video> element which is a child of the element which triggered the event
         //
         var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

         // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
         span.onclick = function() {
             modal.style.display = "none";
         }

             window.onclick = myFunction;

             function myFunction(e) {## 
                  ----------
                  enter code here
                   ##
               if (e.path.length<4  || !e.path.indexOf(modal)) {
                            enter code heremodal.style.display = "none";
               }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `position: fixed;` in the css for the .modal element in order for the modal to stay in place when scrolling.

Also, the body tag of your html (or the element that will contain the modal)  must have a height and width set, preferably 100%. If body doesn't have a height, you won't be able to set heights using percentage values.